# How to set codeigniter for apache server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

**Updated**,
I'm having some issues with deploying codeigniter project on Ubuntu server, i get 404 Apache error when i click on links.

When i put the project in http://roy.my-domain.com/ = /var/www/html/ folder - it's all works fine - but when i added sub directory http://roy.my-domain.com/roy/ = /var/www/html/roy/ - i get 404 errors .

When my url is http://roy.my-domain.com/roy/index.php/about - i get codeigniter 404 error and not apache2.

**The error :**

Not Found

The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at roy.my-domain.com Port 80

Here are my settings :

0 . Checked for rewrite mod in Apache - got "Module rewrite already enabled"

1 . **My project is in /var/www/my-project/**

2 . **In contains the following :**
    application
    system
    public_html
    index.php
    .htaccess

3. **The .htaccess file :**

   < IfModule mod_rewrite.c >
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /html/my-project/
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

   # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

   < /IfModule >
     < IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 index.php
     < /IfModule >
4. **The apache2.conf :**

   < Directory /var/www/ >
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       Require all granted
   < /Directory >

   < Directory /var/www/html/ >
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   < /Directory >
5. **The config.php :**

   $config['base_url'] = 'http://roy.my-domain/my-project/';
      $config['index_page'] = '';
      $config['uri_protocol']  = 'AUTO';
6. **The index.php :**

   (don't work with ../system and ../application)
      $system_path = 'system';
      $application_folder = 'application';
7. **The controllers :**

   (codeigniter default view) Welcome.php
   About_Controller.php
8. **The views:**
   (codeigniter default view) welcome_message.php
   about.php

Locally - all works fine...Thanks

Comment: Could you provide Apache error log?

Comment: Hi -Thanks -  there is no error from Apache server - i can't view any pages other then main page - when click on links - i get 'page cannot be displayed' error

Comment: Viktor - i've set $config['index_page'] = ''; and now i get an error - i update my post with the error content

Comment: So, now must be some errors in Apache error log.

Answer (score 5):

This error can be triggered by the following:

- server misconfiguration (httpd.conf)
- .htaccess issues
- mod_security or similar

  1. Upload your project in "var/www/my_project".
  2. In config file:
     `$config['base_url']  = '';`
     `$config['index_page'] = '';`
  3. Add this code into your .htaccess file to remove index.php and put this .htaccess file in main folder.

     ```
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

       # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L] 

        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
             ErrorDocument 404 index.php
        </IfModule>
     ```

And `Set AllowOverride to All` in your httpd.conf

set the correct permission on the /cache folder, rather than just making the folder writable you need to make it reclusively writable.

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Jay Kareliya -Thanks - but the now i can't access the site at all - when i go to http://my_site.my_domain.com/my_project - it's redirect me to www.my_site.my_domain.com/my_project  - any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>
```

.htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /html/project/

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
    RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=302,L,NE]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)/{2,}[?\s] [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} system|application
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Try this configuration and don't forget to reload Apache.

Answer (score 3):

A simple step for setup CodeIgniter.

1. Download and extract your CodeIgniter public_html or var/www/project where your domain point.
2. Open your project as URL : https://example.com/project . If you get welcome CodeIgniter message then you have to install CodeIgniter successfully.
3. Make sure, mod_rewrite enabled on your server.
4. In database.php > pass your credential
5. write code in .htaccess to remove index.php from url:

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

I think it will be the complete process for setup the project.Make sure mod_rewrite enable on server. Thanks

Comment: Still links can't be displayed - maybe something is wrong in the config.php  i configure base_url  to http://mysite.domain.com and index_page to index.php

Comment: For base_url .. You have to set  $confi['base_url '] ="http://mysite.domain.com"..\

Comment: One more thing... Is your link working with index.php

Comment: Also please check your domain point fine at your ip address.. e.g. hit here http://ping.eu/ping/